# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+ \infty} \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} \frac{1}{2^{2n}}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have the series

$$
\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+ \infty} \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} \frac{1}{2^{2n}}
$$

By using the D'Alembert principle, I obtain $1$. This does not allow me to say anything on the convergence. What can I do to study the convergence?

Comment: Stirling's formula?

Comment: If you know that the central binomial coefficient is $\geq 4^n/(2n+1)$, you can compare the series with the harmonic series.

Comment: are you sure that your sum converges?

Comment: No, by the comment of Zubzub, it must diverge

Comment: No, by Zubzub's comment, it must diverge. What happens when I take $$
\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+ \infty} (-1)^n \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} \frac{1}{2^{2n}}
$$?

Comment: @TheWanderer That could be the subject of a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radius of convergence of $f(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{z^n}{4^n}$ is exactly one by the ratio test.
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$\binom{2n}{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2 \geq \frac{4^n}{n+1}$$
hence $\lim_{z\to 1^-}f(z) = +\infty$ by comparison with the harmonic series.
A more accurate inequality is 
$$ \binom{2n}{n}\geq\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi\left(n+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)}}$$
and actually
$$ f(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z}} $$
for any $z\in[-1,1)$. Have a look at page 15 [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view).