# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+ \infty} (-1)^n \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} \frac{1}{2^{2n}}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have the series

$$
\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+ \infty} (-1)^n \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} \frac{1}{2^{2n}}
$$

What can I say about the convergence or the divergence?

Comment: This is an abstract duplicate of your previous question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2483259/convergence-of-sum-limits-n-0-infty-frac2nn2-frac122n Did you read my last comment?

Comment: Such series is convergent by Leibniz' test, and it converges to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ by the already-found generating function.

Comment: This converges for Leibniz criterion: it's alternating and the general term converges monotonically to zero

Comment: @Raffaele Can you prove it in an answer please?

Comment: @TheWanderer: you already have everything you need in the other answer, just use it (I believe there is little point in asking questions here, if you are not open to learn something from their answers)

Comment: Yes, it is true that that Leibniz criterion holds, I showed it. Nevertheless, I think that in my previous question there is a problem in the answers, since somebody answers there is convergence, while somebody denies this convergence.

Comment: @TheWanderer: if $c_n\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$, then $\sum_{n\geq 1}c_n$ is divergent and $\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^n c_n$ is convergent, clearly. There is no actual disagreement about that.

Answer (score 1):

Use Stirling's formula

$$n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}\,\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\!\left[1+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right],\quad n\rightarrow\infty.$$

Then we have

$$\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\frac{1}{4^n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\left[1+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right],\quad n\rightarrow\infty.$$

The $(-1)^n$ factor then makes the alternating series converge.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n=\frac{(2 n)!}{2^{2 n} (n!)^2}$$
Let's simplify some factorial
$$a_n=\frac{(n+1)_n}{4^n n!}=^{*}\frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma (n+1)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi  n}}+O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3}}\right)$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi  n}}=0$$

$(*)$where $$(n+1)_n =\prod _{k=n+1}^{2 n} k$$
is the Pochammer symbol